# Declare Java Map<String, Object> arguments in Scala?

Tags: scala

Given this Java:

```
Queue.DeclareOk queueDeclare(String queue, boolean durable, boolean exclusive, boolean autoDelete, 
    Map<String, Object> arguments) throws IOException;
```

It's legal to pass `null` like this from Scala:

```
channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, null)
```

What's the declaration in Scala to pass in an empty Map? This:

```
    channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, Map[String, Object]())
```

Results in:

```
found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object]
required: java.util.Map[String,Object]
    channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, Map[String,Object]())
```

And:

```
channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, java.util.HashMap[String,Object]())
```

Results in:

```
object java.util.HashMap is not a value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

val emptyMap = Map.empty[String, Object].asJava
// java.util.Map[String, Object]

channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, emptyMap)
```

Or:

```
channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, new java.util.HashMap[String, Object]())
                                                     // ^ add new here
```

`new java.util.HashMap[String, Object]` (without the parentheses) also works.

Comment: Thanks. `channel.queueDeclare(inputQueueName, true, false, true, Map.empty[String, Object].asJava)` did the trick.